# Mixed precision training implementation

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

So with the release of 1.16 I tried to optimize some of my code for mixed precision and see if I would see a measurable speed up.

I tried two training loops (both with 99% gpu usage on rtx 2060) but I don't measure any speed up, so I would like to show them here to check if my implementation is correct first. My implementation is based on the code sample at https://pytorch.org/blog/accelerating-training-on-nvidia-gpus-with-pytorch-automatic-mixed-precision/

The train function WITHOUT mixed precision:

```py
def train(model, device, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, epoch, iter_meter, writer):
    model.train()
    data_len = len(train_loader.dataset)
    train_start_time = time.time()
    for batch_idx, _data in enumerate(train_loader):
        spectrograms, labels, input_lengths, label_lengths = _data
        spectrograms, labels = spectrograms.to(device), labels.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        output = model(spectrograms)  # (batch, time, n_class)
        output = F.log_softmax(output, dim=2)
        output = output.transpose(0, 1)  # (time, batch, n_class)

        loss = criterion(output, labels, input_lengths, label_lengths)
        loss.backward()

        writer.add_scalar("Loss/train", loss.item(), iter_meter.get())
        writer.add_scalar("learning_rate", scheduler.get_last_lr()[0], iter_meter.get())
        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()
        iter_meter.step()
        
    return loss.item()
```

And the train function WITH mixed precision

```py
def train(model, device, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, epoch, iter_meter, scaler, writer):
    model.train()
    data_len = len(train_loader.dataset)
    train_start_time = time.time()
    for batch_idx, _data in enumerate(train_loader):

        spectrograms, labels, input_lengths, label_lengths = _data
        spectrograms, labels = spectrograms.to(device), labels.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        with torch.cuda.amp.autocast():
            output = model(spectrograms)  # (batch, time, n_class)
            output = F.log_softmax(output, dim=2)
            output = output.transpose(0, 1)  # (time, batch, n_class)

            loss = criterion(output, labels, input_lengths, label_lengths)

        # Mixed precision
        scaler.scale(loss).backward()  # loss.backward()

        scaler.step(optimizer)  # optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step() #Should I also put this steps in the scaler?
        iter_meter.step()

        # Updates the scale for next iteration
        scaler.update()

        writer.add_scalar("Loss/train", loss.item(), iter_meter.get())
        writer.add_scalar("learning_rate", scheduler.get_last_lr()[0], iter_meter.get())
    return loss.item()
```

Thhe main difference is that I pass the inputs to the model and calculate the loss inside `with torch.cuda.amp.autocast():` and later backward with the scaler.

Times for training with both functions take the same time, my thoughts on possible reasons are:

- Automatic mixed precision training from pytorch (making both code functions equal)
- I missed something in my implementation
- My model can't benefit from a speed up from mixed precision training

In case someone wants to check the original model that is being trained I have it on [Github](https://github.com/jiwidi/DeepSpeech-pytorch/blob/Mixed-precission-training/model/deepspeech.py)

Any experience eyes that can give it a look?

Comment: I'm not sure you need the `scaler` with 1.6.0 AMP implementation

Comment: @Shai yes, you do need it